# Time complexity in c++. loops

Tags: c++, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I have been learning DSA, but calculating time complexity is a little difficult

I understand the logic of O(n^2) or O(n)

but what will be the time complexity of and how?:

```
while(n%2 == 0) {
    n/=2;
}
```

It will be O(n/2)? not sure

Comment: Try thinking of the number `n` as a sequence of bits. What does this loop find? What does `n%2 == 0` look for (as a bitstring), and what does `n /= 2` do to the bit representation. Perhaps that will get you started in the right direction

Comment: Worst case, it will be O(log(n)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test it practically to see how much iterations loop will have depending of **n**

```
int main()
{
   int n = 2048;
   int count = 0;
   
   while(n%2 == 0) {
        n/=2;
        ++count;
    }
    std::cout << count;
    return 0;
}
```

So, when n = 1024, count = 10
when n = 2048, count = 11

2^(iteration count) = N;

So, complexity would be O(Log 2 (N))

Answer (score 2):

There's obviously a lower bound of `O(1)` for when `n` is initially odd. But that's not the complete answer.

There is an upper bound.

Here's a hint.  How many loop iterations of executing `n = n/2` for the following initial values of `n`:

```
n = 1   =>  0 iteration
n = 2   =>  1 iterations
n = 4   =>  ?
n = 8   =>  ?
n = 16  =>  ?
n = 32  =>  ?
n = 64  =>  ?
n = 128 =>  ?
```

Now what math function, can `f(n)` be implemented with that can predict the count of iterations given an initial value of `n`?  This will give you an upper bound for the runtime complexity.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate the time complexity of your code, always test for the worst case possible.

For instance, if you try **n = 9**, the `while` won't even enter. So the worst case possible is when you divide **n** more times, and that case would be **n = 2<sup>k</sup>**.

Now, it's easy to see that you need **k** operations for the `while` to finish.

If **n = 2<sup>k</sup>**, then **k = log<sub>2</sub>(n)**, hence the complexity is **O(log(n))**.

Comment: In complexity theory, the base of logarithms doesn't matter, so you can ignore the `2`.   i.e.   O(log_2)   O(log_10) [or any other base] are equivalent.\

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate complexity we must test the worst possible case.

If we write a recurrence relation or the recursive version for your loop, it will look somewhat like

```
T(n)=T(n/2)
```

If we iterate this manually for a few iterations it will look like

```
T(n/2)=T(n/4)
T(n/4)=T(n/8)
...
... and so on
```

So the general case for T(n) will be

> **T(n)=T(n/2 <sup>k</sup>)**
> We know that T(1)=1 since it is constant and to convert n/2 <sup>k</sup> into T(1), we put **n = 2<sup>k</sup>**

Which is gives us the time complexity of your loop which is

> **O(log<sub>2</sub>(n))**